# Where does create-react-app application store it's babel configuration when not ejected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I want to read from JS the babel configuration within a module I am doing.

I do not use webpack, I only use babel with babel cli.

Where can I find the babel configuration of a non ejected application made with create-react-app ?

Comment: It's in the [Webpack config of the `react-scripts/config` directory](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/e1c4d272f8fa1b6ac3f41ac0a9e34be0572e946a/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L344-L433).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create-react-app doesn't have a separate babel config file.

Instead, it uses the preset `babel-preset-react-app`.

You can find more details on the preset here - [babel-preset-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-react-app)

On the other hand, if you're interested in the webpack config for babel, you'll find it here as pointed out by @Tholle in the comments

[webpack.config.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/e1c4d272f8fa1b6ac3f41ac0a9e34be0572e946a/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L344-L433)